# Smooth affine plane curve with non-trivial cotangent sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

> **Question:** Let $A = \mathbb C[x,y]/(f)$ be a non-singular plane curve. Under what conditions is the module of Kahler differentials $\Omega_A^1$ (over $\mathbb C$) a free module?

I am not sure what kind of answer is possible for this question, but I would be interested to hear any thoughts beyond what I have below. My main question though is

> **Main Question:** How can I find an example of a non-singular plane curve where $\Omega_A^1$ is *not* free? What is the easiest example to show is not free?

The following partial results show where *not* to look:

For an elliptic curve $C \subseteq \mathbb P^2$ the cotangent bundle is globally trivial (we even calculated an explicit generator [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610248/generator-for-kahler-differentials-of-an-affine-elliptic-curve/1611297#1611297)). This also follows from the following fact:

> If the partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ are coprime in $\mathbb C[x,y]$, then $\Omega_A^1$ is free.

Proof: Let $p\cdot f_x + q\cdot f_y = 1$ in $\mathbb C[x,y]$. Then $\Omega_A^1$ is cyclic on $D(f_x)$ and $D(f_y)$, generated by $dy$ and $dx$, respectively. It is actually even free in these neighborhoods, as it is a cyclic projective over a domain. Then a generator for $\Omega_A^1$ is given by $q\,dx - p\,dy$.

Comment: If $X$ is irreducible closed  subscheme of $A_{\mathbb{C}}^{2}$ then we know that $\Omega_{X/\mathbb{C}}$ is locally free iff $X$ is nonsingular.

Comment: @Girish Yet globally $\Omega_X$ might be a non-trivial projective module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always free. One has the Euler sequence, $0\to A\cdot df\to \Omega^1_{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}|A\to\Omega^1_A\to 0$. Since $\Omega^1_A$ is locally free of rank one, taking determinants, we have $\Omega^1_A\otimes A\cong \Lambda^2\Omega^1_{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}|A=A$.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!

Comment: the "Euler sequence" that you refer is [06AA](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06AA), right? But why do we have $(f)/(f^2)=A\cdot df$?

Comment: @ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo Yes that's it. The meaning of "$A\cdot df$" is just the submodule of $\Omega_{\mathbb C[x,y]}\otimes A$ (aka the free $A$-module generated by $dx$ and $dy$) generated by $df = f_xdx + f_y dy$. The first map in the sequence by definition sends $f \mapsto df$. It is the injectivity of the first map in the sequence that establishes the identification of $(f)/(f)^2$ with its image $A\cdot df$.